# При нажатии на другой блок закрывать активный?

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать должно быть открыто только 1 меню, при нажатии на другое, предыдущее закрывается. Спасибо

```js
const sectorsList = document.querySelectorAll('.sector-two__circle');

if(sectorsList.length > 0){
  for(var index = 0; index < sectorsList.length; index++){
    const sector = sectorsList[index];
    sector.addEventListener('click', function(e){
      const sectorName = sector.getAttribute('href').replace('#', '');
      const currentSector = document.getElementById(sectorName);
      
      sectorOpen(currentSector);
      
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
}

function sectorOpen(currentSector){
  if(!currentSector){
    return;
  }
  if(currentSector.classList.contains('open')){
    currentSector.classList.remove('open');    
  }else{
    currentSector.classList.add('open');    
  }
}
```

```css
.sector-two__scene{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.sector-two__circle{
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  }
  
.sector-two__description{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
 }
  
.description-sector-two__items{
   display: none;
 }
  
.description-sector-two__items.open{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #161616;
    margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="sector-two__description description-sector-two">
    <a href="#sector_1" class="sector-two__circle circle_1"></a>
    <div id="sector_1" class="description-sector-two__items">
     какой-то текст
    </div>
    <a href="#sector_2" class="sector-two__circle circle_2"></a>
    <div id="sector_2" class="description-sector-two__items">
     какой-то текст
    </div>
    <a href="#sector_3" class="sector-two__circle circle_3"></a>
    <div id="sector_3" class="description-sector-two__items">
     какой-то текст
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sectorOpen(currentSector){
  if(!currentSector){
    return;
  }
  sectorsList.forEach(s => 
    if (s != currentSector && s.classList.contains('open')) { s.classList.remove('open'); }
  );
  if(currentSector.classList.contains('open')){
    currentSector.classList.remove('open');    
  }else{
    currentSector.classList.add('open');    
  }
}
```